# Building dynamic web site with Java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

I am new to java development !
Facing some problem , and bit confused. My purpose is to deploy a website using struts ...
Eclipse
Mysql
Tomcat
The situation is that i have already installed jdk-7u7-windows-i586 and eclipse-java-juno-win32 but i cant do web programming, now do i need to install any jdk ee version from the links below ??
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-downloads-439814.html (OR)        http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html

What about eclipse ?? do i need to download Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers ??

Also Which version of tomcat server should i install ?

Comment: Do you have to use struts? Why not something more modern like JAX-RS?

Comment: When the requirement is like that... i have to develop a website(data base driven) !!

Comment: Is the requirement to use struts, or to be dynamic?

Comment: both dynamic and struts .... but what is JAX-RS all about ??? and alos plz answer me the question athat i have asked ?

Comment: Your question is not a good question for Stack Overflow. It's something you have to decide for yourself. As to what is JAX-RS, that's a big question. There's a lot of information that's easy to find on it.

Comment: Why don't you try following the first two parts of the [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)?

Comment: Well its seems that @bill is more focused in answering what is JAX-RS ? than literally answering the the main question that i posted ? Please answer related to mymain question...

Comment: I am certain you will not need struts. If you did, you would already know what it is, and certainly know how to install Tomcat. Don't bother with it. If you just want a simple dynamic web app that can connect to a DB then don't touch any frameworks until you've learnt the basics. After you've learnt the basics you'll just desire a more complex framework like struts or SPRING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get eclipse bundled with an application server, glass fish, and with java EE. For application development Glassfish will do everything tomcat will, and has support for EJB.

http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/

But to be honest you probably need to start with some basic tutorials on application development with Java EE. Struts is not a beginner concept and if you have never played around with server-side java then it won't be intuitive.